# Replace Gradient colors with ThemeSwift library (Library used for App Theme management)

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, swift5

How to use this library for gradient colors as they haven't mentioned the usage of gradient with ThemeAnyPicker in their documentation.

I am using plist method which is much easier way than the other one. (This library can be used in 2 ways : Index method and Plist method)

Theme library link : https://github.com/wxxsw/SwiftTheme

I have given the code below.

```
@IBDesignable class GradientView: UIView {
    

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        // MARK: - Default gradient (Without applying Swift theme library)
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        
        // MARK: - With Swift Theme library applied
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).theme_colors =  // What should be the code here?
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for color changes and reset the color of the drawing in the callback

Comment: didn't get that..could you please explain? or fill the code above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).